# Google Block my own App Script permission

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried to have a simple script below (yes the url is not valid) but I get `This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.`. It's my own app script project (Google Sheet) yet I get this weird error message. I tried turned off 2-step verification and enable Less secure app access but still doesn't work (5mins ago, I'll give it another try later in case the config change hasn't propagate but I doubt it'll work).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var url = 'the URL of your spreadsheet';   // put URL here
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
}
```

Does anyone have idea how to make it work?

Comment: I might guess that you are in an account of some sort that doesn't allow users to write scripts. If that's the case check with your admin.

Comment: If anyone has any other solutions, consider adding it to  the linked questions above. If, for any reason, you want this reopened, ping me.